SharePoint SE with OIDC authentication and Office Online Server
We have a SharePoint Subscription Edition farm that is connected with an Office Online Server. We configured one of the web applications to use OpenID Connect authentication, implemented by a Keycloak-based solution.
Although SharePoint SE supports OIDC, and the login using this authentication method works in SharePoint itself, we found that the connection to the Office Online Server in this web application is broken, but works perfect in other web applications that utilize Windows based authentication.
Is this behavior documented anywhere, or should the connection to the Office Online Server work officially with OIDC as well?
